# Ubuntu 20 desktop has my external IP

Tags: networking, ssh, openvpn, dhcp

I have a small factor PC connecting to LAN1 port of a router that acts as a wifi bridge to other parts of my network. The traffic eventually leaves the house from a Bell Canada router. Yesterday I returned to use the box after having left it alone for a while, to find that I could not go outside or even ping anything on my own network. I checked the network and it was on DHCP as a client, but it had a strange IP and external gateway. I looked it up and it was my Bell router's external IP and gateway.

All I have installed is OpenVPN, SSH and Ollama servers. The rest are generic linux apps.

Anyone know why please?

Comment: This isn't about Ubuntu, but how your network is configured. Ubuntu uses DHCP to set addresses, but the actual configuration is sent from your router.